# Apple app Feed Bug - Split word

Tags: bug, ios-app, information-display

[image]

Why is the word “ago” split? Is this a bug?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 12.1.2 (Build 16C101)